# Magento Custom form remove file required validation in Edit action

Tags: validation, magento

I am new in magento.

I have create new form in admin side. and added validation for the image upload if i am creating new entry then it will be good validation work perfect but when i want to edit the form then image upload field will be not required. I have added bellow code for the image field validation.

```
$fieldset->addField('filename', 'file', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('banner')->__('File'),
          'class'     => "required-entry",
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'filename',
      ));
```

Can you please how can i remove the required fill validation at edit time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
    'name'      => 'image',
    'class'     => 'required-entry required-file',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Pattern Image'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Pattern Image'),
    'required'  => true,
    'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
));
```

Answer (score 1):

could you please try below code.

```html
$fieldset->addField('filename', 'file', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('banner')->__('File'),
          'class'     => "required-entry",
          'required'  => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') ? false : true,
          'name'      => 'filename',
      ));
```

please make sure that parameter passed in getParam('id') must be id or whatever parameter name in your case

Let me know if you have any query

Thanks

Comment: Hello thank you for ans its working can i ask one more question how can i show thumbnail after field

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you could you please elaborate more ?

Answer (score 0):

/var/www/html/niresh/megento/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Image.php

1. Please open the above file
2. go to this function public function `getElementHtml()`
3. Add class name `required-entry` in this line `*$this->setClass('input-file');*`
   or
4. Comment this line `*$this->setClass('input-file');*` and add this class name `input-file` along with  `*$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(...,'class'     => 'required-entry input-file',*` in function `_prepareForm()`.

or just duplicate the above file and create a new custom varien data form element. And use this new object instead of "image".

Answer (score 0):

don't use 'file', instead use 'image'.

```
$fieldset->addField('filename', 'image', array(
      'label'   => Mage::helper('banner')->__('File'),
      'class'   => "required-entry",
      'required'=> $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') ? false : true,
      'name'    => 'filename',
      ));
```